# Styling loop element in for in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a loop, printing 300 numbers.
I want to set redcolor every 6 and 7 numbers.
Is it possible in js?

Comment: you mean red: 6,7, 13,14, 20,21 or 6,7, 12,14, 18,21?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type you should be able to do this with css and `7n` I would assume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nth-child(6n)` and `nth-child(7n)`

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
for (let i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
  const elm = document.createElement('div');
  elm.innerText = i;
  container.append(elm);
}
```

```css
#container div:nth-child(6n), #container div:nth-child(7n) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```